# port forwarding and canyouseeme.org

Tags: ssh, router, port-forwarding

I'm using a Qwest Q1000 modem/router combo, and believe I have set up port forwarding correctly.

If I go (or you go) to http://canyouseeme.org and type in my IP address(174.29.9.83), and port (22), the web can see me. - It gets a success message.

On my mac, if I turn off remote login, the message says error. So, canyouseeme.org is reaching the mac itself.

But, if I try to ssh my machine @ 174.29.9.83, the connection times out (Operation timed out) every time.

I also have UPnP and NAT-T disabled on the router. And, I am fairly certain I'm not being double NAT-ed (as the modem and router are one and the same for this device.)

What gives?

Comment: If you'd like to test this yourself, go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and use the IP address I provided with port 22

Comment: I started putty, put in your IP address, and I'm currently presented with a login prompt.  What is your issue?

Comment: Don't forget that, unless your router supports "hairpin" routing, you can't test port forwarding from inside your own network, you need to use an independent Internet connection.

Comment: If you make the hairpin routing comment an answer, I'll accept it. This was driving me NUTS. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your router supports "hairpin" routing, you can't test port forwarding from inside your own network, you need to use an independent Internet connection.

Comment: Wow, I spent so much time trying to debug something that was already working on my Bell Home Hub 3000 in Canada. Thanks!